# Cannot read property 'args' of undefined error while compiling a .ts file in Visual Studio Code IDE

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have written a `tsconfig.json` file which contains,

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

And my `HelloWorld.ts` file contains,

```
function SayHello() {
    let x = "Hello World!";
    alert(x);
}
```

But, when I compile this code in Visual Studio Code using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> I'm receiving the below error (in the output window),

```
Cannot read property 'args' of undefined
```

My NodeJS Version is 7.8.0, and TypeScript version is 2.3.4

Can someone help what's going wrong here?

Comment: I could see the same issue reported in typescript's github repository here => https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16850

Comment: Have you tried running `tsc` directly?

Comment: @E_net4 Running `tsc` from the command line works fine.

Comment: Can you try [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16850#issuecomment-312429572) in your project?

Comment: @E_net4 That worked perfectly! Please post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Personally, I'd be more satisfied by knowing exactly what Code is doing wrong by default. I'll certainly enjoy answering the question with this information. Until then, it seems that someone has already posted an answer.

Comment: @E_net4 The answer is in turn your answer (which you have posted in the github forum) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it,This url provides a reliable answer.
url:https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16850.

This might actually be an issue with Visual Studio Code integration, You can try to open the command panel and try typing "configure task runner" and select "TypeScript-tsconfig.json" .Then vscode will automatically generate a .vscode folder under the current Project and generate the following tasks.json file.

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "tsc",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "showOutput": "always"
}
```

Comment: It surprises me that you posted an answer before letting the original suggester of the fix take that opportunity. Not that I mind much in this case, but the lack of proper credit can be an open door to misunderstandings.

Comment: Sorry to borrow your answer,In fact, at first I just gave a link to github.So I received the message above you,Thus causing such misunderstanding.Please believe that I have basic morality.I'm sorry to say that again.@E_net4